# cannot pass arguments to python script when invoke from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have searched SO but couldn't find an asnwer.
I want to invoke a python script(child script) from another python script(main script). I cannot pass arguments from parent to child?
I am expecting "subprocess launched: id1-id2" from the console.
But what I am getting is "subprocess launched:test-default". The subprocess is using the default parameters instead of receiving parameters from the parent script.

```
# parent
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'child.py', 'id1', 'id2'])

# script name: child.py
def child(id, id2):
    print ('subprocess launched: {}-{}'.format(str(id), id2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(id='test', id2='default')
```

Comment: You call `main(..)` instead of `child(..)`.

Comment: Furthermore you can, but these parameters are in `sys.args`.

Comment: sorry didn't get what you are saying. I want a subprocess instead of call main directly. That way my parent scrip can keep going instead of waiting for the child to complete.@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: every script get arguments from command line in `sys.args` but your `child.py` doesn't use `sys.argv`

Comment: @Lisa, ...if that's all you're trying to do, there are cheaper/more efficient ways to `fork()` a copy of your current interpreter with startup-time initialization already done; when you use `subprocess` to start a whole new interpreter, it pays what would otherwise be one-time startup costs a second time. See the multiprocessing module for an example. And of course, there's also threading (though whether that's appropriate depends on implementation details).

Answer (score 2):

The parameters that you pass to a Python process are stored in [**`sys.argv`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv). This is a list of parameters, that works a bit similar to [**`$@`** in `bash` [bash-man]](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) for example.

Note that `argv[0]` is *not* the first parameter, but the name of the Python script you run, as is specified by the documentation:

> **`argv[0]` is the script name** (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).

The remaining parameters are the parameters passed to the script.

You can thus rewrite your `child.py` to:

```
# script name: child.py
from sys import argv

def child(id, id2):
    print ('subprocess launched: {}-{}'.format(str(id), id2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child(id=argv[1], id2=argv[2])
```

Comment: ;) i think you mean: from **sys** import argv